# Where do all the essays go in college?

Tags: publications, writing, grades, policy, databases

At my college I worked in the back room shredding graded essays from various subjects for hours.

Some of them were very good and seems like a gross waste of data and labor.
I wonder is this the policy of all colleges?

https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/40595/can-database-be-collected-from-essays-written-in-college

Comment: I certainly hope my university isn't mining my essays to sell data ....

Comment: Please do not post partial answers or data points as comments.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft how is this to broad if comments were good enough to be an answer. How many answers can come from this? or is it just a bad question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Colleges have to keep everything that influences grades of students for a certain time in order to resolve disputes over grades. In our case it is 3 years.

Comment: and given confidentiality rules, shredding is probably the best plan after the hold time.

Comment: "Everything that influences grades" is putting it a bit strongly. I only have to keep final exams, and only for one year.  I can discard/destroy graded homework, midterms, project reports, and anything else _except_ final exams at the end of the semester.

Comment: @JeffE so you can get rid of them but I am interested is can you keep them to collect data?